# Is there a package in Julia similar to dplyr?

Tags: dataframe, julia

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
using DataFrames
a = DataFrame(A = randn(1000), B = randn(1000), C = randn(1000));
N = 1000;
```

Like I want to divide every column by N (if it's numeric), so in R I would do the following (using dplyr):

```
a <- a %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, function(x) x/N)
```

Is there something like this in Julia?

(I am trying to avoid for loops, and to do the operation column by column)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DataFrames documentation has a [Comparison with dplyr](https://dataframes.juliadata.org/latest/man/comparisons/#Comparison-with-the-R-package-dplyr) section. You can see that `mutate`s in dplyr correspond to `transform`s in DataFrames.jl. `transform` also allows many ways to select the columns to operate on, which can be used for the `mutate_if` functionality.

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [10, 15, 20, 25], y = [12.5, 20, 101, 102], colors = [:red, :blue, :green, :cyan])

4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x      y        colors 
     │ Int64  Float64  Symbol 
─────┼────────────────────────
   1 │    10     12.5  red
   2 │    15     20.0  blue
   3 │    20    101.0  green
   4 │    25    102.0  cyan

julia> transform(df, names(df, Number) .=> (c -> c / 5) => identity)
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y        colors 
     │ Float64  Float64  Symbol 
─────┼──────────────────────────
   1 │     2.0      2.5  red
   2 │     3.0      4.0  blue
   3 │     4.0     20.2  green
   4 │     5.0     20.4  cyan
```

`names(df, Number)` returns a vector of the names of the columns whose elements are `Number`s (i.e. any `Number` subtype).
`c -> c / 5` divides the column by 5 (which Julia applies element-wise by default).
`.=>` applies the above transformation on each column individually, rather than all together.
`identity` just tells `transform` not to change the names of the columns.

(This answer previously suggested `transform(df, Cols(in(names(df, Number))) => ByRow((c...) -> c ./ 5) => identity)` as the solution. Thanks to @Bogumił Kamiński in the comments for suggesting the current, simpler method.)

`transform` above returns the result dataframe, without changing `df`. You can use
`transform!(df, names(df, Number) .=> (c -> c / 5) => identity)`
(note the `!` after `transform`) to do this operation in-place and update `df` directly instead.

Comment: A bit shorter would be `transform(df, names(df, Number) .=> ByRow(c -> c / 5) .=> identity)`.

Comment: That's much neater. I'd like to update the answer with that suggestion, if you don't mind. Does doing it `ByRow` have any advantage here? In my answer I used it because I wanted to keep the function very simple and without iteration, but in this case the broadcast takes care  of that need. So `transform(df, names(df, Number) .=> (c -> c / 5) .=> identity)` itself works.

Answer (score 2):

`transform` is very powerful and it may feel more natural if you come from a `dplyr` background, but I fill in this case using a simple loop over columns and broadcasting over items more natural.

Don't be afraid of loops in Julia: they are (generally speaking) as fast as vectorised code and can be written very concisely using array comprehension:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x = [10, missing, 20, 25], y = [12.5, 20, 101, 102], colors = [:red, :blue, missing, :cyan])
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y        colors  
     │ Int64?   Float64  Symbol? 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │      10     12.5  red
   2 │ missing     20.0  blue
   3 │      20    101.0  missing 
   4 │      25    102.0  cyan

julia> [c .= c ./ 5 for c in eachcol(df) if nonmissingtype(eltype(c)) <: Number];

julia> df
4×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y        colors  
     │ Int64?   Float64  Symbol? 
─────┼───────────────────────────
   1 │       2      2.5  red
   2 │ missing      4.0  blue
   3 │       4     20.2  missing 
   4 │       5     20.4  cyan
```

In the above example, the dot is to indicate broadcasting (each element of the column `c` is the result of the division of the old value by the scalar 5) and I have used `nonmissingtype` to account for the case where you may have missing data.